# Mathematical term for the largest integer multiple that is less than or equal to a given value

Tags: terminology

I would like to ask if there is a mathematical term for "the largest integer multiple of $n$ that is less than or equal to $a$". In software engineering, this is commonly implemented as $(a / n)\cdot n$ or $a − (a \% n)$ where both $a$ and $n$ are integers. For example, if $n=4$ and $a=10$, the result is $8$ because $4$ goes into $10$ two times and two times $4$ is $8$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

This is related to the [floor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions) of $\frac{a}{n}$, denoted $\lfloor\frac{a}{n}\rfloor$, the desired multiple is $\lfloor\frac{a}{n}\rfloor n$. In general, $\lfloor x\rfloor$ is defined as the largest integer less than or equal to $x$. The difference $a-\lfloor\frac{a}{n}\rfloor n$ is the remainder from dividing $a$ by $n$, and $\lfloor\frac{a}{n}\rfloor$ is the quotient from division with remainder, they are implemented by MOD and DIV functions in many computer algebra systems. But, I am afraid, there is no special name for $\lfloor\frac{a}{n}\rfloor n$ itself.